# Nginx - pass proxy_cache value with proxy_cache_bypass

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have multiple `proxy_cache_path` directives and in the `http` block and I want to pass the value of the `proxy_cache` variable to a lua modul. However, I do not want to define the route (/tmp/cache/BackendA or /tmp/cache/BackendB, etc) more than once. I would rather store it in a variable.

My config snippet:

```
http {
    proxy_cache_path /tmp/cache/BackendA keys_zone=BACKEND_A_PROXYCACHE:50m max_size=1g use_temp_path=off inactive=20m;
    proxy_cache_path /tmp/cache/BackendB keys_zone=BACKEND_B_PROXYCACHE:100m max_size=2g use_temp_path=off inactive=30m;
    # ...

    server {
        # ...

        location =/BackendA/ServiceA {
            # ...
            proxy_cache BACKEND_A_PROXYCACHE;
            # set $cache_folder_path "/tmp/cache/BackendA";
            set $cache_folder_path $proxy_cache;
            proxy_cache_bypass $cache_folder_path;
        }
        
        location =/BackendB/ServiceB {
            # ...
            proxy_cache BACKEND_B_PROXYCACHE;
            # set $cache_folder_path "/tmp/cache/BackendA";
            set $cache_folder_path $proxy_cache;
            proxy_cache_bypass $cache_folder_path;
        }
    }
}
```

If i try to use `set $cache_folder_path $proxy_cache;` command then i can't start the nginx server.

Error message:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown "proxy_cache" variable
```

I'm looking for a more elegant solution than the commented part:
`set $cache_folder_path "/tmp/cache/BackendA";`

The question is what should I do now? Will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

if you using Linux and if is support apt-get, for cache module

```
apt-get install nginx-extras
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the opportunity to use it.